# PHP replace line at the top of a text file with fgets

Tags: php, fopen, fgets

I'd like to use php to open a file and replace just one line that will be near the top. Since it's near the top I don't want to read the whole file into memory. Here is what I've tested but I think I am not understanding how to backspace over the line once I identify it using strpos():

```
<?php

$file = "test-file.php";
$new_value = "colors:orange green violet;";
$fhandle = fopen($file, "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$replaced = "false";

while ($replaced === "false") {
    $line = fgets($fhandle);
        if (strpos($line, "colors:")) {   //find the colors line
        //Should I be moving the file pointer back here?
        //Once I find the line, how do I clear it?
        $line = $new_value;
        fputs($fhandle, $line);
        $replaced = "true";
    }
}
fclose($fhandle);
?>
```

Contents of test-file.php:

```
 fruit:apples bananas;
 colors:red blue green;
 cars:ford chevy;
```

Note: Each line in test-file.php ends with a semicolon.

Comment: ``fgets()`` includes the newline char(s), so you probably want to run ``$line = trim(fgets($fhandle))`` or otherwise handle the new line before making string comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the whole file in, in order to overwrite that line, because the file you describe is a set of non-fixed lines (or put another way is a stream of characters).  You won't be able to replace a part of it in-place, of a different size, without affecting characters in other lines.

You don't have to read the whole thing into memory all at once.  The `fgets()` approach lets you read just a line at a time.  The least memory intensive way to do this is to write all values to a new file, then delete (`unlink`()) the old file, and `rename()` the new file to the old filename.